# How can I find the value of elements in web scraping using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read some of the data(the values inside some of the tables) from this website http://cdn.ime.co.ir using the following code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://cdn.ime.co.ir'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.findAll())
```

But when I print the result I get something like this:

```
<td id="SAFSH98_FirstTradedPrice"> 

                    </td>
<td id="SAFSH98_HighTradedPrice"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_LowTradedPrice"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_LastTradedPrice">
<b></b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<!-- 2 -->
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume2"></td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice2"></td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice2"> 

                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume2"> 

                    </td>
<td id="FTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
<td id="HITPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
<td id="LWTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
<td id="LTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<td>
<div id="SAFSH98_InitialMargin" title="وجه تضمین اولیه">
</div>
</td>
<!-- 3 -->
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume3"></td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice3"></td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice3"> 

                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume3"> 

                    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<td>
<div id="SAFSH98_MaintenanceMargin" title="وجه تضمین لازم">
</div>
</td>
<!-- 4 -->
<td class="BidStyle" id="BTV" title="حجم کل تقاضا">
<b>-</b>
</td>
<td colspan="2" title="Total">حجم کل
                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="ATV" title="حجم کل عرضه">
<b>-</b>
</td>
<td colspan="4" id="CCFD" title="نوع ارز">ریال
                    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<!-- 5 -->
<td id="SAFSH98_PersianLastTradingDate"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_PersianOrdersDateTime" title="زمان آخرین به روزرسانی سفارشات"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" id="SAFSH98_PersianFirstTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام اولین معامله"></td>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" id="SAFSH98_PersianLastTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام آخرین معامله"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="Spr">
<td class="Spr" colspan="9"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="Header">
<td title="Size">اندازه قرارداد
                    </td>
<td colspan="4" title="Settlement Price">قیمت تسویه روزانه
                    </td>
<td title="Volumeحجم معاملات انجام شده">حجم
                    </td>
<td colspan="2" title="ارزش معاملات انجام شدهValue">ارزش
                    </td>
<td title="OIموقعیت های تعهدی باز بازار">موقعیتهای باز
                    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<td id="SAFSH98_ContractSize"> 

                    </td>
<td colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_LastSettlementPrice"> 

                    </td>
<td id="SAFSH98_TradesVolume" rowspan="2"></td>
<td colspan="2" id="SAFSH98_TradesValue"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_OpenInterests"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<td id="SAFSH98_ContractSizeUnitFaDesc" title="دارایی پایه"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_PersianLastSettlementPriceDate" title="تاریخ قیمت تسویه روزانه"></td>
<td colspan="2" id="SAFSH98_TradesValueCurrencyFaDesc"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_C_OpenInterestsChanges" style="direction: ltr" title="تغییر نسبت به روز قبل"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>, <tbody>
<tr class="Header">
<td rowspan="2" style="width: 200px" title=" Futures Contract">کدقرارداد<br/>
</td>
<td colspan="2" title="Bid">تقاضا
                    </td>
<td colspan="2" title="Ask">عرضه
                    </td>
<td colspan="4" title="Traded Prices">قیمت های معامله شده
                    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="Header">
<td title="Vol">حجم
                    </td>
<td title="Price">قیمت-ریال
                    </td>
<td title="Price">قیمت-ریال
                    </td>
<td title="Vol">حجم
                    </td>
<td title="قیمت اولین معامله انجام شدهFirst">اولین
                    </td>
<td title="بالاترین قیمت معامله شدهHigh">بالاترین
                    </td>
<td title="پایین ترین قیمت معامله شدهLow">پایین ترین
                    </td>
<td title="قیمت آخرین معامله انجام شدهLast">آخرین
                    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<!-- 1 -->
<td rowspan="2">
<div id="SAFSH98_ContractCode" title="">
</div>
</td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume1"></td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice1"></td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice1"> 

                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume1"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_FirstTradedPrice"> 

                    </td>
<td id="SAFSH98_HighTradedPrice"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_LowTradedPrice"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_LastTradedPrice">
<b></b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<!-- 2 -->
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume2"></td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice2"></td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice2"> 

                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume2"> 

                    </td>
<td id="FTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
<td id="HITPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
<td id="LWTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
<td id="LTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<td>
<div id="SAFSH98_InitialMargin" title="وجه تضمین اولیه">
</div>
</td>
<!-- 3 -->
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume3"></td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice3"></td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice3"> 

                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume3"> 

                    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<td>
<div id="SAFSH98_MaintenanceMargin" title="وجه تضمین لازم">
</div>
</td>
<!-- 4 -->
<td class="BidStyle" id="BTV" title="حجم کل تقاضا">
<b>-</b>
</td>
<td colspan="2" title="Total">حجم کل
                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="ATV" title="حجم کل عرضه">
<b>-</b>
</td>
<td colspan="4" id="CCFD" title="نوع ارز">ریال
                    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<!-- 5 -->
<td id="SAFSH98_PersianLastTradingDate"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_PersianOrdersDateTime" title="زمان آخرین به روزرسانی سفارشات"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" id="SAFSH98_PersianFirstTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام اولین معامله"></td>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" id="SAFSH98_PersianLastTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام آخرین معامله"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="Spr">
<td class="Spr" colspan="9"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="Header">
<td title="Size">اندازه قرارداد
                    </td>
<td colspan="4" title="Settlement Price">قیمت تسویه روزانه
                    </td>
<td title="Volumeحجم معاملات انجام شده">حجم
                    </td>
<td colspan="2" title="ارزش معاملات انجام شدهValue">ارزش
                    </td>
<td title="OIموقعیت های تعهدی باز بازار">موقعیتهای باز
                    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<td id="SAFSH98_ContractSize"> 

                    </td>
<td colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_LastSettlementPrice"> 

                    </td>
<td id="SAFSH98_TradesVolume" rowspan="2"></td>
<td colspan="2" id="SAFSH98_TradesValue"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_OpenInterests"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="Contents">
<td id="SAFSH98_ContractSizeUnitFaDesc" title="دارایی پایه"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_PersianLastSettlementPriceDate" title="تاریخ قیمت تسویه روزانه"></td>
<td colspan="2" id="SAFSH98_TradesValueCurrencyFaDesc"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_C_OpenInterestsChanges" style="direction: ltr" title="تغییر نسبت به روز قبل"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>, <tr class="Header">
<td rowspan="2" style="width: 200px" title=" Futures Contract">کدقرارداد<br/>
</td>
<td colspan="2" title="Bid">تقاضا
                    </td>
<td colspan="2" title="Ask">عرضه
                    </td>
<td colspan="4" title="Traded Prices">قیمت های معامله شده
                    </td>
</tr>, <td rowspan="2" style="width: 200px" title=" Futures Contract">کدقرارداد<br/>
</td>, <br/>, <td colspan="2" title="Bid">تقاضا
                    </td>, <td colspan="2" title="Ask">عرضه
                    </td>, <td colspan="4" title="Traded Prices">قیمت های معامله شده
                    </td>, <tr class="Header">
<td title="Vol">حجم
                    </td>
<td title="Price">قیمت-ریال
                    </td>
<td title="Price">قیمت-ریال
                    </td>
<td title="Vol">حجم
                    </td>
<td title="قیمت اولین معامله انجام شدهFirst">اولین
                    </td>
<td title="بالاترین قیمت معامله شدهHigh">بالاترین
                    </td>
<td title="پایین ترین قیمت معامله شدهLow">پایین ترین
                    </td>
<td title="قیمت آخرین معامله انجام شدهLast">آخرین
                    </td>
</tr>, <td title="Vol">حجم
                    </td>, <td title="Price">قیمت-ریال
                    </td>, <td title="Price">قیمت-ریال
                    </td>, <td title="Vol">حجم
                    </td>, <td title="قیمت اولین معامله انجام شدهFirst">اولین
                    </td>, <td title="بالاترین قیمت معامله شدهHigh">بالاترین
                    </td>, <td title="پایین ترین قیمت معامله شدهLow">پایین ترین
                    </td>, <td title="قیمت آخرین معامله انجام شدهLast">آخرین
                    </td>, <tr class="Contents">
<!-- 1 -->
<td rowspan="2">
<div id="SAFSH98_ContractCode" title="">
</div>
</td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume1"></td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice1"></td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice1"> 

                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume1"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_FirstTradedPrice"> 

                    </td>
<td id="SAFSH98_HighTradedPrice"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_LowTradedPrice"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_LastTradedPrice">
<b></b>
</td>
</tr>, <td rowspan="2">
<div id="SAFSH98_ContractCode" title="">
</div>
</td>, <div id="SAFSH98_ContractCode" title="">
</div>, <td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume1"></td>, <td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice1"></td>, <td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice1"> 

                    </td>, <td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume1"></td>, <td id="SAFSH98_FirstTradedPrice"> 

                    </td>, <td id="SAFSH98_HighTradedPrice"></td>, <td id="SAFSH98_LowTradedPrice"></td>, <td id="SAFSH98_LastTradedPrice">
<b></b>
</td>, <b></b>, <tr class="Contents">
<!-- 2 -->
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume2"></td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice2"></td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice2"> 

                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume2"> 

                    </td>
<td id="FTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
<td id="HITPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
<td id="LWTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
<td id="LTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>
</tr>, <td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume2"></td>, <td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice2"></td>, <td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice2"> 

                    </td>, <td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume2"> 

                    </td>, <td id="FTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>, <div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChanges">
</div>, <span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_FirstTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>, <td id="HITPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>, <div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChanges">
</div>, <span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_HighTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>, <td id="LWTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>, <div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChanges">
</div>, <span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LowTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>, <td id="LTPC" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
<div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChanges">
</div>
<span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>
</td>, <div dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChanges">
</div>, <span dir="ltr" id="SAFSH98_C_LastTradedPriceChangesPercent"></span>, <tr class="Contents">
<td>
<div id="SAFSH98_InitialMargin" title="وجه تضمین اولیه">
</div>
</td>
<!-- 3 -->
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume3"></td>
<td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice3"></td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice3"> 

                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume3"> 

                    </td>
</tr>, <td>
<div id="SAFSH98_InitialMargin" title="وجه تضمین اولیه">
</div>
</td>, <div id="SAFSH98_InitialMargin" title="وجه تضمین اولیه">
</div>, <td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidVolume3"></td>, <td class="BidStyle" id="SAFSH98_BidPrice3"></td>, <td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskPrice3"> 

                    </td>, <td class="AskStyle" id="SAFSH98_AskVolume3"> 

                    </td>, <tr class="Contents">
<td>
<div id="SAFSH98_MaintenanceMargin" title="وجه تضمین لازم">
</div>
</td>
<!-- 4 -->
<td class="BidStyle" id="BTV" title="حجم کل تقاضا">
<b>-</b>
</td>
<td colspan="2" title="Total">حجم کل
                    </td>
<td class="AskStyle" id="ATV" title="حجم کل عرضه">
<b>-</b>
</td>
<td colspan="4" id="CCFD" title="نوع ارز">ریال
                    </td>
</tr>, <td>
<div id="SAFSH98_MaintenanceMargin" title="وجه تضمین لازم">
</div>
</td>, <div id="SAFSH98_MaintenanceMargin" title="وجه تضمین لازم">
</div>, <td class="BidStyle" id="BTV" title="حجم کل تقاضا">
<b>-</b>
</td>, <b>-</b>, <td colspan="2" title="Total">حجم کل
                    </td>, <td class="AskStyle" id="ATV" title="حجم کل عرضه">
<b>-</b>
</td>, <b>-</b>, <td colspan="4" id="CCFD" title="نوع ارز">ریال
                    </td>, <tr class="Contents">
<!-- 5 -->
<td id="SAFSH98_PersianLastTradingDate"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_PersianOrdersDateTime" title="زمان آخرین به روزرسانی سفارشات"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" id="SAFSH98_PersianFirstTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام اولین معامله"></td>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" id="SAFSH98_PersianLastTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام آخرین معامله"></td>
</tr>, <td id="SAFSH98_PersianLastTradingDate"></td>, <td class="DateTimeStyle" colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_PersianOrdersDateTime" title="زمان آخرین به روزرسانی سفارشات"></td>, <td class="DateTimeStyle" id="SAFSH98_PersianFirstTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام اولین معامله"></td>, <td colspan="2"></td>, <td class="DateTimeStyle" id="SAFSH98_PersianLastTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام آخرین معامله"></td>, <tr class="Spr">
<td class="Spr" colspan="9"></td>
</tr>, <td class="Spr" colspan="9"></td>, <tr class="Header">
<td title="Size">اندازه قرارداد
                    </td>
<td colspan="4" title="Settlement Price">قیمت تسویه روزانه
                    </td>
<td title="Volumeحجم معاملات انجام شده">حجم
                    </td>
<td colspan="2" title="ارزش معاملات انجام شدهValue">ارزش
                    </td>
<td title="OIموقعیت های تعهدی باز بازار">موقعیتهای باز
                    </td>
</tr>, <td title="Size">اندازه قرارداد
                    </td>, <td colspan="4" title="Settlement Price">قیمت تسویه روزانه
                    </td>, <td title="Volumeحجم معاملات انجام شده">حجم
                    </td>, <td colspan="2" title="ارزش معاملات انجام شدهValue">ارزش
                    </td>, <td title="OIموقعیت های تعهدی باز بازار">موقعیتهای باز
                    </td>, <tr class="Contents">
<td id="SAFSH98_ContractSize"> 

                    </td>
<td colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_LastSettlementPrice"> 

                    </td>
<td id="SAFSH98_TradesVolume" rowspan="2"></td>
<td colspan="2" id="SAFSH98_TradesValue"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_OpenInterests"></td>
</tr>, <td id="SAFSH98_ContractSize"> 

                    </td>, <td colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_LastSettlementPrice"> 

                    </td>, <td id="SAFSH98_TradesVolume" rowspan="2"></td>, <td colspan="2" id="SAFSH98_TradesValue"></td>, <td id="SAFSH98_OpenInterests"></td>, <tr class="Contents">
<td id="SAFSH98_ContractSizeUnitFaDesc" title="دارایی پایه"></td>
<td class="DateTimeStyle" colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_PersianLastSettlementPriceDate" title="تاریخ قیمت تسویه روزانه"></td>
<td colspan="2" id="SAFSH98_TradesValueCurrencyFaDesc"></td>
<td id="SAFSH98_C_OpenInterestsChanges" style="direction: ltr" title="تغییر نسبت به روز قبل"></td>
</tr>, <td id="SAFSH98_ContractSizeUnitFaDesc" title="دارایی پایه"></td>, <td class="DateTimeStyle" colspan="4" id="SAFSH98_PersianLastSettlementPriceDate" title="تاریخ قیمت تسویه روزانه"></td>, <td colspan="2" id="SAFSH98_TradesValueCurrencyFaDesc"></td>, <td id="SAFSH98_C_OpenInterestsChanges" style="direction: ltr" title="تغییر نسبت به روز قبل"></td>, <script type="text/javascript">
    function GetServersList() {
        Fut_Live_Loc_Service.GetServersList(onServersListDataLoaded, onFailure, onUserContext);

    }

    function onServersListDataLoaded(sender) {

        NextServer = sender;    

    }
    GetServersList();


</script>, <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
LoadDataWithTimer('CSSH98');LoadDataWithTimer('OSFMO98');LoadDataWithTimer('OSFSH98');LoadDataWithTimer('SAFMO98');LoadDataWithTimer('SAFSH98');//]]>
</script>]
```

As you can see it seems there is no values(numbers) in the result, so how should I read the values of the tables?

ّEDIT: For example there is an element like this inside the last table of the page: `<td id="SAFSH98_LastTradedPrice" style="display: table-cell;">۱۱۹,۰۰۰</td>` and I like to read it's value, the number `۱۱۹,۰۰۰` but in the above response that I get from the `soup` it doesn't contain the numbers!

EDIT2: I put a picture to make it cleared to say what exactly I want. This picture shows one of those tables and I specified some fields(numbers) that I like to read from the page with green boxes.

[image]

Comment: what values are expected?

Comment: What are you referring to value in this?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I mean numbers inside the tables.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal:  I mean numbers inside the tables

Comment: @user3486308, you need to indicate an element path to those values. For now - it sounds vague. Point the needed attributes of an element

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: You mean this `//*[@id="SAFSH98_LastTradedPrice"]`

Comment: "so how should I read the values of the tables?" What values are you referring to, what do you want?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal: This is a stock market web site. Inside the tables there are some numbers that I like to read them.

Answer (score 0):

You should find tables using soup.find_all("table") after that you can get their context using for loop , for an example if you want to view values of table data go for bellow code.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://cdn.ime.co.ir'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
number_of_tables = soup.find_all('table')
print("total number of tables are : ",len(number_of_tables))
for i in number_of_tables:
    print(i)
    # print(i.text) for viewing only context without html tags
    print("""<<<<table ended>>>>""")
```

Comment: Thanks Rajat, but there is same problem in your code, there is no value(number) in the printed result. Please read the `EDIT` part of the question.

Comment: I don't want the number of tables, what I want is the numbers that are existence inside the tables. These numbers are prices or volumes of stocks.

Comment: Could you provide me a screenshots at rajat4665@gmail.com because this website is in arabic or urdu and I am not able to understand. If you provide  more details then may be i can help you.

Comment: Please read the EDIT2 part. I sent a pic that I think will clear my question.